# How do I run delayed job inserts in the backgroud without affecting page load - Rails 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have an RoR application like posting answers to a question. If a user answers to a question, notification messages are sent to all the users, who watch-listed the question, who tracks the question and to the owner of the question. I am using delayed jobs for creating the notification messages. so, While creating answer, there are many inserts into delayed job table going on,which is slowing down the page load. It takes more time to redirect to the question show page after the answer is created.

Currently I am inserting into answers table using AJAX request. Is there any way to insert into delayed jobs table in background after the AJAX request completes?

Comment: so why exactly do you create jobs for each person from the watchlist instead of creating one job that does all the notifiaction for all the people from the watchlist. that would make way more sense!

Comment: I am working on already existing application and in the process I am also learning rails. Currently I need a quick fix for my problem, so I am looking for a plugin or a gem, which will help me.

Comment: delayed_job *is* the gem for this.   The problem sounds like you need to move the call to "delay" further up your alorithm so that only one delayed job gets entered, and the job of looking up all that info and creating messages takes place in the delayed job.

Comment: Thank you... In my rails app, the delayed jobs gem looks up into delayed_jobs table to perform all the message sending inserts. THis happen as a background process. My problem is with the delayed jobs gem itself. That is, creating an answer includes many many inserts into delayed_jobs table itself which is later used by delayed jobs gem to deliver notifications. I would like to know if i can perform the inserts into the delayed_jobs table in the background without making the user wait for a long time for the inserts into delayed_jobs table and then for the page to reload. I hope i am clear.

Comment: You are missing the point.  Rewrite the code that calls delayed_job, so that it only inserts one row into delayed_jobs table.  Then let the delayed job sort out the multiple actions.

Comment: @DGM One reason to have multiple jobs is that if one fails, other jobs can still be processed.

Answer (score 3):

As we have been trying to say in comments:

It sounds like you have something like:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.delay.some_long_operation
end
```

This ends up inserting a lot of rows into delayed_jobs.  What we are suggesting is to refactor that code into the delayed job itself, roughly:

```
def delayed_operation
  User.all.each do |user|
    user.some_long_operation
  end
end

self.delay.delayed_operation
```

Obviously, you'll have to adapt that, and probably put the `delayed_operation` into a model library somewhere, maybe as a class method... but the point is to put the `delay` call outside the big query and loop.

Answer (score 0):

I really advice doing this like that in a separate process. Why has the user to wait for those  meta-actions? Stick to delivering a result page and only notifying your server something has to be done.

Create a separate model PostponedAction to build a list of 'to-do' actions. If you post an answer, add one PostponedAction to this database, with a parameter of the answer id. Then give the results back to the user.

Use a separate process (cron job), to read the PostponedAction items, and handle those. Mark them as 'handled' or delete on succesfull handling. This way, the user is not bugged by slow server processes.

Comment: That's what delayed job is all about

Comment: Isn't that what delayed job is for? How do you propose to insert the values to the PostponedAction Model? Is there a background process for that?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the email jobs you currently have, invent another type of job handling the creation of these jobs.

```
def email_all
  User.all.each do |user|
    user.delay.email_one()
  end
end

def email_one
  # do the emailing
end

self.delay.email_all()
```

This way the user action only triggers one insert before they see the response. You can also track individual jobs.